# make php form-generated variable available in two php files

Tags: forms, php-include

I have a form, `Form_hour.php`, that is loaded into the browser, and allows a user to select an hour. The form sends the variable `$hour`, via `action="get"`, to the file `View_A.php` which uses `$hour` to query a database, and then loads `View_A.php` into the browser window, showing data for the selected hour.

In View_A, there is a button allowing the user to switch to View_B. The idea is that when the user clicks on View_B, the file `View_B.php` loads in the browser. `View_B.php`, like `View_A.php`, queries the database using that same `$hour`.

So what I want is for the same user-selected variable `$hour` to be available to both `View_A.php` AND `View_B.php`. i.e., if the user selects 6 a.m., then I want View_A and View_B to show data for 6 a.m.

I thought that having `Form_hour.php` send `$hour` to the file `common.php`, and then include `common.php` in `View_A.php` and `View_B.php` would work. But I keep getting the error **"Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4327 bytes)"** in `View_A.php`.

Does anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might want to use sessions ( http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php ) or simply make the View_B a link to view_B.php with parameter hour set ( i.e. "view_B.php?hour=6" ) and read it in view_B.php trough $_GET ( http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Comment: I think sessions MIGHT be the way to go, but let's say the user has a look at both views for 6 a.m. then wants to go and look at 9 a.m. Using "session_start(), 6 a.m. persists in the system and I can't get it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken you could just do it like I wrote below.
This will direct the user to a difrent page, but will do what you want.

form_hour.php

```
<form action="View_A.php" method="post">
     your code
</form>
```

View_A.php

```
<?php
$_POST['hour'] = $hour
// query database and do something with it!
?>

<form action="View_B.php" method="post">
     <input type="hidden" name="hour" value=<?php print('"'.$hour.'"'); ?>>
     <input type="submit" ..... >
</from>
```

Like you asked, If you want the form as a var.

```
<?php
$_POST['hour'] = $hour
// query database and do something with it!

$form = '<form action="View_B.php" method="post">
     <input type="hidden" name="hour" value="'.$hour.'">
     <input type="submit" ..... >
</from>';

//to show it just print/echo it.
print($from);
?>
```

View_B.php

```
<?php
$_POST['hour'] = $hour
// query database and do something with it!
?>
```

Comment: thanks -- that might do the trick. However, the <form> is already part of a php variable, i.e.  value must be in single quotes. Any idea how to "quotify" the expression <?php print('"'.$hour.'"'); ?>> ?

Comment: thanks, yes that would do it. My problem has evolved since I posted this... now grappling with AJAX so as to not have to query same db twice